# Find a name in Excel with different character and return another column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

pic : Google Spreadsheet

(You need to see the image, so you will know what I mean, hopefully)

I have some testcase that I want to try, how can I get the "yess" in C3. My logic condition to get that was if A column is "a" and then check each of "a" in B column that has "3" then return the C so we can get the "yess" value. But I am stuck at implementing using `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP` and `XLOOKUP`. Any ideas?

When I tried `xlookup`, with no combination its only return the first of "a"

Comment: Your screenshot is Google-Sheets I believe? Are you sure your current Excel tags are correct?

Comment: @JvdV thanks for correcting, i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `FILTER` : [filter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) for multiple criteria:

```
=FILTER(C1:C4,(A1:A4="a")*(B1:B4=3))
```

Result:

[image]